# How can webservers detect replayed login attempts?

Tags: http, fiddler

I found a strange thing when i'm coding a net-spider to a specific website.

I used fiddler and chrome(as well as other web-browsers) to log-in a website(HTTP, not https) and get all package(as well as the cookie) that sent and received:(
first package 'Get' to request the log-in page and the cookie, then use the cookie received to request verification code and some other pics. and then send login request with userid, password and verification code to server and server response with correct info)

Then I log-out and Clear all Cache and Cookie and use Fiddler to Relay(Simulate) the whole process (Since I know all packages' format that i should send): request the log-in page to get cookie, use the cookie to request all pics( auth code image included), and then use the cookie and auth code to request login(userid and password are correct)...but failed.

I'm sure the failure is not caused by invalid userid or password or auth code, and i believe there is nothing special on the front-end(html,script are checked), but it puzzled me a lot **how can the server tell i used browser or not in back-end**..

I'm not request anybody to solve the specific problem. i'm just wanna know DOES ANYONE HAS HAD SIMILAR PROBLEM i described?

the specific website is not important and i must say the whole practice is completely harmless! i'm not doing any hacking stuff, on the contrary it will help some people.

======================================================
I've finally figured out the reason: the log-in page has a hidden input() and i carelessly overlooked that since its value looks almost the same every time. Web server can not detect replayed log-in attempts if we simulated all necessary HTTP request packages.
Thank you guys~

Comment: Have you compared the responses you get when you log-in through your browser and when you re-run the steps in Fiddler ? What leads you to think the problem is the site detecting you're not using a a browser ?

Comment: The most used (and quite stupid) method to tell whether a client is a browser or not, is evaluating the User-Agent header – did you send one with your Fiddler requests that matches a real browser?

Comment: @Bartdude, thank for your answer. Yes, i've compared responses from browsers and from replay of fiddler. all responses except the log-in step are the same. since requests are composed by merely a html page, a jquery-1.3 and a query-base64 encoded(i've checked the script has not been changed). and 5 pics(one is auth code, others are page element). i found nothing special on front-end(html,script) and i re-run all request based on previous format with cookie i get (cookie will not change during whole process in previous trail with browser)..so i cannot figure out how the site tell the difference

Comment: @CBroe, thanks for your answer. Yes, user-agent are the same as the previous request. since i only change the cookie section in fiddler and do the 'replay'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servers cannot magically tell whether they're talking to Fiddler or not.

If Fiddler and your client are sending the exact same requests, that means that the server in question is using a "one time token" (sometimes called a nonce) in its login form. If the server ever sees the same token again, it rejects the logon. Sometimes the nonce isn't sent directly, and is instead used in the computation of a "challenge-response" as occurs in authentication protocols like NTLM. In other cases, the nonce is a CAPTCHA, which helps prevent you from using a bot to automatically log in to a site like this.

Unless you can share more details of the target site (or a SAZ file of the login process), it's unlikely that folks will be able to help you.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer and elaboration! since the saz file include my friend's private info(password). i can paste the website here. its http://bksjw.hust.edu.cn/   it's a website of a school where students can see their grades and curriculum. and once again, my practice is harmless. i'm working on a app for stu to check their grades and curriculum and other stuff faster.

Comment: This page's login form includes a CAPTCHA; the server likely binds the CAPTCHA's "answer" to a back-end session variable, which means that replaying the original answer to a subsequent request is guaranteed to fail. (CAPTCHAs are typically used for purposes exactly like this-- to prevent use of web forms by bots).

Comment: sorry i replay late and thank you for your answer~Truely, i know the session in back-end is bind to the CAPTCHA(which i called 'auth code' in original description), so i get the CAPTCHA at previously(after get the new cookie) and replace the data (uid,psw,CAPTCHA) of the login request and send to the server, but i failed. That's the reason makes me puzzled. I think i still has the .saz file that i did the experiment. if you would like to help, i can send you via email(if will not trouble you too much).